# Java HashMap ConcurrentModification Exception despite using synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I have a hashmap used in multiple threads at the same time. To make it thread safe I put it into a synchronized block:

```
private final Map<Long, DeviceConnection> mapConnections = new HashMap()<>;

...

synchronized (mapConnections) {
        List<Long> toClear = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Long, AndroidSocketConnection> entry : mapConnections.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().isReadyToRemove())) {
                removed++;
                toClear.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        for(Long toC : toClear) {
            mapConnections.remove(toC);
        }
    }
```

I thought if I put it into synchronized block I do not have to care about such stuff, but this Exception is thrown:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>
> at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)
>
> at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1476)
>
> at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1474)
>
> at myPackage.network.DeviceHandler.doClearing(DeviceHandler.java:51) // **->** **this line contains  the for loop head    of the code I showed**
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Is there other code elsewhere that operates on `mapConnections`?

Comment: yes sure. Thats why I am using synchronized block. I put stuff and remove stuff from this map all the time in other threads

Comment: do those other threads also access through `synchronized (mapConnections)` blocks?

Comment: No, but I have references onto objects in this HashSet in which I change attributes not in synchronized blocks could that be a problem?

Comment: Well that explains the `ConcurrentModificationException`. As for operating on other objects without synchronization, yes it is definitely a problem. It won't cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` but you'll have bugs that are hard to understand and difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will only be thread-safe if *every* access (both reads and writes) to the map is performed via a `synchronized` block.

`ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown when the map is being iterated on while it is being modified.

I would suggest you switch to a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which is thread-safe and will be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Sounds good, but I put all other read stuff on this HashSet into synchronized blocks aswell.

Comment: But I have references onto objects in this HashSet in which I change attributes not in synchronized blocks could that be a problem?

Comment: @julien-100000 Do those changed attributes affect the result of the `hashCode` method? That would be very bad.

Comment: yes Im pretty sure they do, because the class is annotated with Lomboks @Data

Comment: If I use ConcurrentHashMap do I still need to care that the hashcode is not changed or can I ignore this then? @BasilBourque

Comment: No, it won't work if you change the hashCode of an item's key. You will have to remove the entry first, make the alterations and add an updated version afterwards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959545/why-does-changing-the-hashcode-of-an-object-used-as-a-key-in-a-hashmap-make-a-lo But your key is `Long`, so it probably won't be affected by this issue. It doesn't matter if you change the hashCode of one of the values, only the key.

Comment: Ah okay. Does it work if I remove my own hashcode implementation and you the default one from the Object class?

Comment: @julien-100000 [*What's the implementation of hashCode in java Object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13602501/642706). The upshot: When depending on `hashCode`, such as usage as a key in a hash-based map, you should implement `equals` & `hashCode` using a stable value within the object such as an employee ID for `Employee` class, or a product ID field for a `Product` class. "Stable" means the value will not change while your app is running, or at least not change during the life of the hash-based usage such as being a key in a map.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you both for your help! :)